# how to change the size of BarButtonItem according to the title

Tags: ios, swift

How do I change the size of a UIBarButtonItem according to the title.
I tried using sizetoFit() but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding it programmatically. And give the width accordingly.

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)) // adjust the width here.
button.setTitle("Your Title", for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```

Comment: This is not changing the width according to the title

Comment: Is there any way to do it if I have created the button in storyboard and accessing it by an outlet